# Keras, Image Registration, Full Convolutional Network

Tags: image-processing

I'm doing image registration, essentially figuring out where a 60x60 image is on a larger 74x74 image.   The images are different modalities - one is visual, the other IR - so simply matching (openCV - matchTemplate) or other techniques (like Mutual Information) don't work.   So I'm trying a fully convolutional Siamese network.   (Two references at end - but neither with source.)

I'd like the siamese part of the network to be identical in terms of structure/weight so that the features identified will be comparable.   My challenge is the 'fully convolutional' part.   From the latest paper "Benefitting from the fully convolutional structure, we are able to feed the left and right branches with different-sized input image patches."

Question - how does a Fully Convolutional Network do it's thing?    And how can I fix my code?
[What I want/What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is3Tl.png)

**Code:**

```
def convUnit(model,nFilters,strides=1):
    model.add(Conv2D(nFilters, padding="same", kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=strides))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.0001, scale=False, center=False))
    model.add(Lambda(K.relu))

def getL2():   # From 'hardnet', w/ minor modes
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, padding="same", kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(dimT,dimT,1)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.0001, scale=False, center=False))
    model.add(Lambda(K.relu))
    convUnit(model,32)
    convUnit(model,64,strides=2)
    convUnit(model,64)
    convUnit(model,128,strides=2)
    convUnit(model,128,strides=2
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(8,8)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.0001, scale=False, center=False))
    return model   # of size 1,1,128

def createNewModel():
    model = getL2()  # One model for images

    left_unk = Input(shape=(None,None,1))
    right_unk = Input(shape=(None,None,1))
    encode_L = model(left_unk)
    encode_R = model(right_unk)

    # Combine - options include 1x1 Conv (per paper), dot product,
    # some matmul, ...
    #m2 = Dot( 3 )([encode_L, encode_R]) # not sure of axes here - tried combos

    siamese_net = Model([left_unk,right_unk],m2)
    return siamese_net
```

**Results:**
When I run a simple prediction, the dot product fails with...

```
In[0].dim(1) and In[1].dim(1) must be the same: [1,1,1,128] vs [1,3,3,128] on node dot_11/MatMul
```

**Thanks!**

References:
 - Zhang, et al, Registration of Multi-Modal Remote Sensing Image based on Deep Fully Convolutional Neural Network

Comment: Mutual information is supposed to work with images from different modalities.

Comment: Tried MI and some other techniques.    Very good when the images are fairly similar.   Very poor when they aren't, say thing like roads are black in visual and white in IR.    Hundreds of examples (btw all obvious to the human eye) where MI works (say ~10-20%) and fails (the rest.)